# Require attributes on elements with unknown names?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to write XML with unknown named elements with a few known attributes and an unbounded number of unknown attributes. How is this done, something like the following?

**XML**

```
<Nodes>
 <COM.US.BattleShip UUID="adaKAj62ja" "X="4" Y="4" cannons="5" crew="50">
 <COM.US.Cruiser UUID="dhRTV53ga" "X="4" Y="4" destroyed="true">
</Nodes>
```

**XSD**

```
<xsd:element name="Nodes">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element>
        <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:attribute name="UUID" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
         <xsd:attribute name="X" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
         <xsd:attribute name="Y" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
         <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: A few misconceptions to clear away first. In XML Schema, all elements are named. I suspect you mean 'elements with unknown names' rather than 'anonymous elements'. Secondly, in XML Schema the type of an element determines its content. You cannot describe an element with an unknown name but known content. Finally, an XML attribute cannot repeat, so the maxOccurs=unbounded on the attribute declaration is illegal.

Comment: Thanks I have edited that. So if i want to have an unknown amount of attributes, I should add them as inner tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XSD 1.0 cannot require attributes on elements with unknown names.**

You could write assertions in XSD 1.1, but really, you'd be better off re-working your XML design.  Rather than allow any element names, you could use predefined generic element names so that you can then use normal XSD 1.0 attribute requiredness constraints.  You could capture `COM.US.BattleShip` as an *attribute value* rather than an *element name*.

```
<Nodes>
  <Node name="COM.US.BattleShip" UUID="adaKAj62ja" X="4" Y="4" cannons="5" crew="50"/>
  <Node name="COM.US.Cruiser" UUID="dhRTV53ga" X="4" Y="4" destroyed="true"/>
</Nodes>
```

**If this XML design is acceptable, then an XSD can easily be written in XSD 1.0 to cover your concerns:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Nodes">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Node" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="UUID" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="X" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Y" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: ah yes wonderful, I was just curious if it was possible. The main concern was having more attributes than defined in the XSD, without having to resort to inner tags.